# Select with recursive join on matching row

Tags: mysql

**Given**:

Table `friends` - list of users and their friends:

```
 id | user  | friend |
----+-------+--------+
  1 | John  | Pete   |
  2 | John  | Rock   |
  3 | Pete  | Steve  |
  4 | Pete  | Liz    |
  5 | Pete  | Rock   |
  6 | Bob   | Pete   |
```

**Question**:

I need a query that will fetch only those friends of **John**'s friend **Pete** that are friends of **John** (i.e. mutual friends of John & Pete). As a result, only row ID `#5` should be returned, because John and Pete have only one mutual friend - **Rock**.

**My attempt**:

This yields no results:

```sql
select T1.* FROM friends T1
INNER JOIN friends T2 ON T2.user=T1.friend
WHERE T1.user='John' AND T1.friend_id='Pete' AND T2.friend=T1.friend
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM friends AS t1
JOIN friends AS t2 ON t1.friend = t2.friend
WHERE t1.user = 'Pete' AND t2.user = 'John'
```

Since you want mutual friends, the join condition should specify that the friend is the same for both users.

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jET1jXis8WeuJsuXEkVjrW/0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the friends of **John** and the friends of **Pete**, and then relate the results with the "friend" column.

```
SELECT
    f1.*
FROM
    friends f1,
    friends f2
WHERE
    f1.user = 'John' AND f2.user = 'Pete' AND f1.friend=f2.friend
```